# Electric circuit which flips voltage

Tags: voltage, output, input

Is there an electric circuit which flips voltage? For instance if the input is Vi>0V then the output will be 0V and if the input is 0V then the output is >0V.

And i am not reffering to the NOT gate , I want voltage not current.

I have searched but couldn't find anything.Can we do this with Op-Amps somehow?

Comment: "NOT  gate" doesn't imply that it's a current output, at all. You have misunderstood something there. A logical inverter (=NOT gate) is *exactly* what you describe.

Comment: Ok but in a NOT gate a resistor is connected parallel to the transistor and  the state of the gate is if current passes through the resistor.If the transistor is on , almost no current passes through the resistor and we say it has a value of 0.

Comment: "in a NOT gate a resistor is connected parallel to the transistor": um, you seem to be thinking to one very special *implementation* of a NOT gate (which we don't know). If that implementation doesn't invert the input, it's not a NOT gate, so it's even less clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Yes i just wikipedia it. I understand now.

Comment: GReat! Usually, it's a good idea to consult wikipedia first, then ask, because it increases the likelihood of asking a question to which the answer helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. A basic comparator circuit. Source: [All About Circuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/video-tutorials/op-amp-applications-voltage-comparator/).*

A comparator's output switches output state depending on the relative voltages at the input. In the case of Figure 1 it has been configured to switch high when V<sub>IN</sub> exceeds V<sub>REF</sub>. For your case you would swap the two inputs to get the inverse action.

> For instance if the input is Vi > 0 V then the output will be 0 V and **if the input is 0 V then the output is > 0 V**.

You will have to assign some tolerance to your definition of 0 V. e.g., V<sub>IN</sub> ≤ 100 mV or similar. You then set V<sub>REF</sub> to that value and the comparator will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to a CMOS NOT gate. CMOS NOT gates do work with voltage input and voltage output. CMOS inputs do not draw current, except for maybe microampere of leakage current. CMOS output also provides voltage output.

Comment: I think your first sentence is missing something like a "BJT" or so?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: No, it was not know the OP means BJT. Will edit.